# Domain & file server migration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, migration, file-server

Our company has a client who is in a spot of trouble and has asked us for advice. Their support/host company has gone bust and they want to use this opportunity to upgrade their servers.
They have an older domain that they need to migrate from (Dobbde.com running server 2003) into (Dobbde123.com running 2012). They have two domain controllers in Dobbde.com (2003) and we will have two domain controllers in the new domain which run 2012.
What would be the best way to do this? Windows Migration tool?
They also want to migrate their file server from 2003 to 2012.
They have a number of mapped user drives from Group Policy under docs.Dobbde.com:
d:\ Durham, e:\ France, f:\ NZ, and  Z:\Germany 
D:\Durham has a number of user shares on it which need to be migrated one at a time: D:\Sales D:\Boats D:\AdminD:\Haulgate

What would be the best way to do this part of the migration? Is there a way to do this using windows migration tools?? Should we use Robocopy or a similar tool for this part of the work? 
Apologies if this is muddled, like I say the host company has gone bust and we are in a tight spot. Am I missing something?I realise this is pretty brief but any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

o
Regards,

Damian Ferns

Answer (score 1):

Why do they need to migrate the domain? That's just making a lot of work for (probably) no gain.

They can install new DCs of the appropriate version, upgrade the domain, decomm the old DCs, and then work on installing new fileservers and migrating the shares/content.

If they also migrate domains, they now have to migrate users and workstations, which is a pain and doesn't sound like it would be worth it.

Comment: They have said they want to move now whilst they need to make changes anyway.

Does the fact two domain controllers are running change anything? All guides I have found only mention migrating the one DC.

Could you provide details on the best way to movedthe fileserver and its shares over?. Thanks,

DF